# Javascript Stopwatch - Control From other Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this scenario.  I want to start, stop & reset a stopwatch from an "admin page" but I would like to show the current stopwatch(time only) on a "client page" when the Admin has pressed the START button on the admin page.

Its for a sport event.

Basically the players will be able to see the stopwatch time on a large TV.  But the buttons to control the stopwatch must be on admin page managed by one of the employees.  There is a whole bunch of info that will be echo'd from MySQL hence why we don't want to show the buttons for controlling the stopwatch on the "client" page.  Hope this makes sense.  Please & thank you.

*note - I am beginner in terms of javascript.

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }
    
    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
timer();


/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}
```

```html
<h1><time>00:00:00</time></h1>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Maybe look at [socket.io](https://socket.io/)?

Comment: please see above edit.

Comment: You will need a backend to communicate between the two pages. What technology will you use? `asp.NET MVC`, `node`, `Ruby on Rails`? You will then need  to use that with `SignalR` or `socket.io` depending on what you pick

Answer (score 0):

If it client and admin page run on the same machine, you can use localstorage and listen for change events on the client and apply the changes through the master (must be same pc and same browser)

Comment: unfortunately they not on the same machine or browser.  Because its a smart TV that uses the "client" url.